# How to show elevation data in cesium

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, cesium

I am publishing postgis data using geoserver with 4 dimensions including elevation.

How to show this layer in cesium 3d globe with elevation or displacement value?

Answer (score 1):

When you say you have 4d data, is your terrain data static or time dynamic (and you have other gis data that is 4d)?

In regards to showing terrain in Cesium, you will need to provide a *global* terrain model via a TerrainProvider.  There are several TerrainProviders that Cesium can support, as shown in the [Cesium Terrain and Water Tutorial](http://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/Terrain-Tutorial/).

What resolution is your elevation data?  If the resolution of your data isn't too high (say 90m or greater) and you're able to use gdal commandline tools to merge and tile your data into a global tile pyramid, there is a geoserver plugin that treats elevation bil files as if they were imagery.  However, I would advise against using geoserver for terrain, as every tile request must prepare a mesh from raster data in javascript on the client.  This will be impractical for streaming terrain of moderate to good resolution.

If performance is a requirement, you should instead look into using the quantized-mesh spec.  This open format was created for efficient streaming and rendering of terrain.  The Cesium Terrain Tutorial linked above uses an internet accessible tileset that adheres to the quantized-mesh spec.

Comment: I think the user wants to show his data above the globe in a z-axis. Like a plane flying or a satellite. I have the same request.

Comment: Cesium Terrain Builder c++ tool is what I use or python script generate folder of XYZ .terrain tiles in quantized mesh terrain format.

Comment: OpenMapTiles Subscription include s quantized mesh terrain tiles and RGB elevation tiles

Comment: The geoserver terrain provider for cesium has been depreciated and no longer supported